# How to move xmlReader to parent element from its child element?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader, xmlwriter

I'm writing basic C# program to read old XML file and write it to new XML with some modification.i.e I'm adding new element to some existing elements.But I want to add that new element at specific position so if I move reader to that specific position then I cant return it back to parent.Is there any way to do this.With Doc parser I'm able to do this.But I want to perform this task with SAX parser.

Answer (score 2):

Using SAX parser there is no way to do this.

> ...SAX parsers operate on each piece of the XML document **sequentially**.[<sup>Wiki</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML)

The same can be found in the documentation for [`XmlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.xml.xmlreader) class:

> Represents a reader that provides fast, noncached, **forward-only** access to XML data.[<sup>MSDN</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.xml.xmlreader)

Comment: @user2098710, As far as I know - no.